# Не отображается наличие других ответов, если кто-то дал ответ одновременно

Tags: дефект

Пример: [Найти сумму модулей элементов массива, которые идут после элемента со значением 0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/729990/178988)

Два ответа (мой и ещё один) даны одновременно с точностью до секунды в 15:52:50. При этом плашка, свидетельствующая об ещё одном ответе, не появилась на странице. О существовании второго ответа я узнал из комментария, написанного к моему.

## Вот как я вижу страницу:

> [image: как я вижу страницу]

## И вот что на ней есть вообще:

> [image: и что на ней есть вообще]

## Должна бы показываться плашка о новом ответе:

> [image: скриншот плашки]

Comment: Не понял, какое поведение вы хотите? Чтобы когда вы публикуете ответ, на странице показывались также и все ответы, данные за то время, пока вы писали ответ?

Comment: А что если соседний был дан на полсекунды позже?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, стандартная плашка "появился 1 новый ответ" (или как она там точно сформулирована), при нажатии на которую подгружаются ответы. А полсекунды нем бывает - они в базе время хранят так, что секунда - минимальная единица измерения.

Comment: В вашем «вот как она должна выглядеть» нет ничего про плашку.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, исправил.

Comment: Отлично. Я картинки выделил, а то сливается всё.

Comment: Кстати, чем вы делаете скриншоты длиной в три экрана?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, конкретно эти - в Хроме F12, Ctrl+Shift+P, "screen", Capture Full Size Screenshot. Ещё есть расширение FireShot. А ещё почти все проги для захвата экрана умеют области с прокруткой. PS: Добавил скриншот плашки.